flutterfire configure not working (Timeout Exception) - Firebase
I'm trying to connect my new Flutter project with Firebase. I've successfully executed the following commands:
Logged into Firebase:
firebase login

Installed FlutterFire CLI:
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

However, I'm running into a timeout issue when I try to run:
flutterfire configure

Problem:
Every time I run flutterfire configure, I get the following error:
⠼ Fetching available Firebase projects...

TimeoutException after 0:00:15.000000: Future not completed

What I've Tried:
1. Checked Firebase Authentication:
firebase logout and firebase login
firebase login --reauth
2. Tested with Different Network Connections:
Switched between different Wi-Fi networks.
Tried using mobile data.
Turned off antivirus temporarily.
3. Environment Details:
Flutter Version: (flutter  --version) latest
Firebase CLI Version: ( firebase --version) lastest
FlutterFire CLI Version: ( flutterfire --version) latest
Operating System: Windows 10.
This is not my first app to connect with firebase!

I've only ever seen this happen on accounts with a very long list of projects or when I'm on a very bad network connection. Either way, you can try passing in the project id on the command line: flutterfire configure --project <your project id>: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78466246/209103

try to close firewall and try again
flutterfire configure
